# UIImage not a compile-time constant, Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

I'm writing an iPhone program where a bunch of images have to animate onto the screen from out of bounds and then back off the screen. I'm trying to create some UIImages that I can use for the animations, using images that I've added to a group in the program, but I keep getting an error that says "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant."

Here is the specific code I'm using to initialize the images, being put into a ViewController.m file:

```
UIImage* name = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"imagename.png"];
```

What do I need to add or change in order to make this work? Can I use an NSImage for animation or does it have to be a UIImage? Thanks.

Edit: Fixed by putting the code in the appDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageWithContentsOfFile:` takes an `NSString` that is a path to the file. The name you're supplying has no path, although I wouldn't expect the error you're seeing because of that. If you use `imageNamed:` instead, you'll have better luck using a filename with no path.

Comment: Need to see a bit more code then; need more context to see where the line you did post is, relative to the rest of your code structure. Edit your original post with some more code.

Comment: Edited; I am just trying to initialized the image in the same ViewController.m file where the image is then going to be used. Should I do this in the .h file instead, or somewhere else?

Comment: Well, @lxt suggested that the error was due to the context in which you placed that statement. Of course, it needs to be part of a method, not just hanging out randomly in your .m file.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]`.

The problem with `initWithContentsOfFile:` is you need to provide a full path to the image on the disk, which would make you get the path to your Application's documents directory and then append your filename to it.

`imageNamed:` also caches the images currently being used by the application so it doesn't have to go back to the disk each time you request an image.

Answer (score 1):

So, to answer a few of those questions:

`NSImage` is not available on iOS - `UIImage` is its equivalent. So you don't get to use `NSImage` I'm afraid.

Regarding your compiler error: you should probably post the code where you create that image. This error normally occurs when you try to create an object outside of a function. This answer may go someway to helping you:

[Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)

...a number of answers here are concentrating on your use of `imageWithContentsOfFile`, but with that sort of compiler error I'm virtually certain that actually that's not the case: your error is happening somewhere else. So check the answer I've linked to and see if that helps.

Comment: ...not if you're targeting iPhone. `NSImage` *does not exist* on iOS.