# Xcode semantic issue "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant "

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have this Error with calling NSMakeRange method. What I'm doing wrong?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//
NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(12, 5);
```

Answer (score 5):

When you initialize a variable outside of a function or method, you can only use constant values: you can't execute any code. Here the problem is that you're trying to execute `NSMakeRange`. (See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant), which is similar).

The solution is to declare `range1` but not assign any value to it, and then implement an `+initialize` method that sets the value. `initialize` is a class method that is invoked before any other methods are called in your class.

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (range1 == NULL) {
        range1 = NSMakeRange(12, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why then <code>NSRange range1 = {12, 5};</code> works properly without errors?

Comment: Because `{12, 5}` is a constant. `NSMakeRange(12, 5)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

`initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant` error will throw when you try to initialize an variable inside @implementation and out side any methods. You can declare variables before @implementation so that it can be accessed by every methods. And you can declare variable inside a method so that it can be visible inside that method.