# Putting a character range in UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How come this code isn't working to set a character limit in XCode?
I wrote it in my viewDidLoad() under ViewController.m

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
NSFormatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.allowsFloats= NO;
formatter.minimum= @5;
formatter.maximum= @15;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [formatter numberFromString: textField.text]!= nil;
}
```

Errors:
http://imgur.com/h83hzsw

Comment: In this particular case, Xcode error messages are actually helpful. Read them.

Comment: @Kreiri Ok.. I changed the file type to C++ which fixed one error but now I am still getting all of these and I'm stuck. http://imgur.com/DKLnblG

Answer (score 1):

From the errors, it looks like you're not using this code inside an actual method (such as `viewDidLoad`) Since you need it in multiple methods, you'll need your `formatter` to be accessible throughout the class. Try moving things around a bit:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter;
}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    formatter.allowsFloats= NO;
    formatter.minimum= @5;
    formatter.maximum= @15;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'textFieldShouldReturn'" on line: 44 - http://pastebin.com/SpBV6hvB

Comment: The formatting and the order of where you are putting your code is still very much off. I would suggest looking through the code on some sample projects or tutorials. For instance, you're trying to put the `textFieldShouldReturn` method inside the method of an `IBAction`. Not the way things work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error '*Initializer element is not a compile-time constant*' because you are initialising the variable `NSNumberFormatter* formatter` not in a method or function and the compiler therefor expects a constant value.

See SO answer here for more detail - [Initializer element is not a compile-time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860360/xcode-semantic-issue-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)

Comment: Ok so I tried this and I went from 10 errors to 1. Now I'm stuck because it's saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'textFieldShouldReturn'" on line: 44. Here's my new code: http://pastebin.com/qJc7bP16 Can you please help I've been trying to figure this out all day.

Comment: I've checked your newly updated code and you're still initialising the variable named formatter inside the implementation but outside of any methods or functions. Is there a reason why it's not an ivar or property? What is the required scope of the variable named formatter?

Comment: I was trying to put a character limit on selected text boxes but I scrapped the whole idea and removed everything for now, it's causing a lot of errors and I am still a beginner with Objective-C. But now I'm just trying to run my application and it's giving me this error: /Users/Julian/Desktop/Journey/Journey/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.