# "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this code:

```
- (NSString *) calculate: (uint) position {
    static NSArray * localArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: self.container.objects ];
    // some un related code
    return obj;
}
```

The compiler complains saying: "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant". It happened when I added "static" to localArray. But why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6143107/94687 was the same question. The only special thing in your question is the explicit adding of `static` keyword to a variable inside a function body (but this must be equivalent to having a variable in the global scope, as in that question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because `[NSArray arrayWithArray: self.container.objects ]` isn't a compile-time constant, it's an expression that must be evaluated at runtime.  In C and Objective-C, `static` variables inside functions must be initialized with *compile-time* constants, whereas C++ and Objective-C++ are more lenient and allow non-compile-time constants.

Either compile your code as Objective-C++, or refactor it into something like this:

```
static NSArray *localArray = nil;
if (localArray == nil)
    localArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: self.container.objects ];
```

Which is fairly similar to the code that the compiler would generate under the hood for a `static` variable initialized with a non-compile-time constant anyways (in actuality, it would use a second global flag indicating if the value was initialized, rather than using a sentinel value like `nil` here; in this case, we are assuming that `localArray` will never be `nil`).  You can check out your compiler's disassembly for that if you want.

Comment: I'd recommend using `dispatch_once()` to initialize the `localArray`.  It is thread safe and very efficient.

Answer (score 5):

You just can't initialize a static variable with a non-static value that will be known/modified at runtime.

You should probably do something like this:

```
static NSArray *localArray = nil;
localArray = ...;
```

The first instruction will be executed once in your app lifecycle.
The second instruction will be executed every time the calculate: method is called.

Nevertheless, pay attention to the fact that using static variables can lead to buggy behaviors if not done properly so if you feel uneasy with these, you should probably not use them.