# Objective C Singleton - why the initial nil assignment?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

I am writing a singleton in ObjectiveC and saw this implementation in many sites I looked at. I really do not understand the nil assignment in the first raw.
Since the block in dispatch_once (to my humble understanding...), how does this method return the previously assigned value (inside the block) and not nil.

```
 + (id)sharedManager {
        static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
        });
        return sharedMyManager;
    }
```

P.S - I noticed this question was asked once here but was not resolved and non of the unswears explain this clearly - [Why is assigned a nil to singleton's static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614692/why-is-assigned-a-nil-to-singletons-static-variable)

Comment: The comment to related question says: The advantage of the former is that it works, the latter doesn't even compile. This one pretends to be very clear.

Answer (score 5):

The `sharedMyManager = nil` assignment is **not necessary** because
**static** variables are automatically initialized to zero.
You can simply remove it.

In addition, the `dispatch_once()` guarantees that `sharedMyManager` is assigned
a value before it is used.

Also note that `dispatch_once()` uses the fact that the `onceToken` is initialized
to zero automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In C based languages, such as Objective-C, static variables are only initialized once. So the `nil` assignment only happens the very first time the code is executed.

Then the call to `dispatch_once` only happens once (that is its purpose), so the static variable is then set to the desired value just the one time.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't initialize your static variable, it can initially have garbage data.

Static variables are initialized once. So in the `+sharedManager` message, the line where the static variable is declared is only run once, and in subsequent calls that line is skipped.

That's why this is the 'standard way' of using static variables inside functions.

Comment: In C, Objective-C, C++ and Objective-C++, static variables and extern variables are always initialised to zero unless the programmer writes something else. So it is absolutely impossible to have garbage data at that point, and that has been part of C since the 70's.