# NSString constant pointer to constant pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, constants

I have a global constant:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const ENGModelItemText; // .h file
NSString *const XYZConstant1 = @"XYZConstant1"; // .m file
```

... and I would like to create `XYZConstant2` that would point to `XYZConstant1`. I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
NSString *const XYZConstant2 = &XYZConstant1
```

I played with `*` and `&` a bit but can't get it right. I'd like to get rid of `#define` for `XYZConstant2` that I use now.

Comment: Why does it matter if they point to exactly the same object or not - you should be using `isEqual:` to compare :)

Comment: Using `==` and `const` is faster.

Comment: If you're after speed why are you using strings at all - use an `enum` :)

Comment: As dean says, never rely on using == on an NSString. If you're in that tight of an inner loop with a comparison, find another solution than comparing strings.

Comment: Why? Comparing an `enum` and a pointer (doesn't matter it's pointing to a string) are both super-fast, aren't they?

Comment: Building things first to be "super-fast" makes them fragile in ObjC (also in most languages). Build them to be super-robust and easy to understand. Then optimize for speed where required. A program that crashes is always the slowest program.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm not comparing strings using `==`. I'm comparing *constant pointers*. It's fast and reliable, no crashing at all. Apple does the same throughout the Cocoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a compile-time alias like this in C (and therefore in ObjC). You can create a runtime alias by declaring `XYZConstant2` inside of a function or method, but not as a static. Compare this pure C, which creates the same error:

```
const char * const foo;
const char * const bar = foo;
```

(See also [Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant).)

Typically when this kind of aliasing is required (usually because a string constant was renamed), you use a `#define` (much as I hate defines).

That said, you should not rely on the fact that two object pointers are the same address unless you mean "it is this object" rather than "it has this value." (And you never mean that for strings because strings only have value.) Write to the semantics, not the implementation details. Don't prematurely optimize comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Just FYI - I use these pointers in a `NSMapTable` (strong pointer-to-pointer mapping). Also thank you for all the additional tips.

Comment: const char * const isn't a compile time constant, it's a variable pushed on the stack, which is constant only a compile time,but with it's memory representation (and it's value could be changed as well).#define creates a (pre-) compile time constant without anything in memory.

Comment: I thought that this was inside a function, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

this is a constant, so compile time. If you want to point it, you can't with a constant.

Comment: In fase of declaration you can make point a constant to another constant.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, have you tried this in ObjC? This answer is correct. You cannot assign a static constant pointer to another static constant pointer at compile time.

Comment: Yes I can.I tried to compile this code just replacing &XYZConstant1 with XYZConstant1 and it works.The compile error was because &XYZConstant1 isn't a pointer to NSString, but a pointer to pointer to NSString.

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood the question.