# How do I add a character to an already existing string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablestring

When I make:

```
NSString x = @"test"
```

How do I edit it so that it becomes "testing"?

And when I put:

```
NSMutableString x = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
```

There is an error that says:

Initializer element is not a compile-time constant.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When declaring `NSMutableString`, you missed the asterisk:

```
NSMutableString *x = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
// Here --------^
```

With a mutable string in hand, you can do

```
[x appendString:@"ing"];
```

to make `x` equal `testing`.

You do not have to go through a mutable string - this will also work:

```
NSString *testing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ing", test];
```

Comment: I added the asterisk just now and I am still having the same error

Comment: @NikitaJerschow Could you post a larger code snippet then? It sounds like you are declaring this variable outside the scope of a function (e.g. a "global"). It does not work like that in Objective C: you need to put initialization in a function.

Comment: The error stays the same even if I directly copy and paste your code
let me post something

Comment: @NikitaJerschow Now I'm nearly certain that you are doing it outside of a function.

Comment: NSString *test = @"Test";
NSString *testing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ing", test];


- (IBAction)button0:(id)sender {
    
    NSLog(test);
    
}

Comment: outside of a function meaning that it should be inside these brackets                   <function>{
        <here>
    }

Comment: @NikitaJerschow Yes, initialization like that needs to go inside curly braces of one of the functions that you have, for example, your init method. Take a look at this answer ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6143171/335858)) for info on how it is done.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your `NSString` or `NSMutableString` as `*x`. These are pointers to objects.

To change a string in code is quite easy, for example:

```
NSString *test = @"Test";
test = [test stringByAppendingString:@"ing"];
```

And the value in `test` will now be `Testing`.

There are a lot of great `NSString` methods, both instance and class methods, for manipulating and working with strings. Check the documentation for the complete list!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add multiple or single strings to an existing NSString use the following

```
NSString *x =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"test",@"ing"];
```