# Cannot set values to an object in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development.

I have a class called Pet

```
@interface Pet : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *petName;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *petBreed;
@end
```

In one of my methods I am trying to set the value for a declared object of type Pet:

```
Pet *selectedPet;

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *currentPetTemp,*currentBreedTemp;
currentPetTemp = cell.textLabel.text;
currentBreedTemp = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
selectedPet.petName = currentPetTemp;
selectedPet.petBreed = currentBreedTemp;
NSLog(@"%@ Name1: %@",selectedPet.petName,currentPetTemp);

return indexPath;
```

}

The NSLog displays the correct value for 'currentPetTemp' but 'null' for `selectedPet.petName`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You havenot initialised it... do the following:

```
Pet *selectedPet=[[Pet alloc]init];
```

or,

```
 Pet *selectedPet=[Pet new];
```

EDIT:

As per your comment `Initializer element is not a compile time constant` This warning is shown when you define a variable outside the scope of any method. This place is only for constant values.

You need to alloc-init in viewDidLoad / init / awakeFromNib.

Comment: Thanks but now its giving an error "Initializer element is not a compile time constant".

Comment: new is not a conventional constructor method name in objective-c. If one was to make a Class method to create an empty instance of our object we should follow the example of `NSArray` et al and create the method `+(instancetype)pet` called like: `[Pet pet];`

Comment: I use `new` as my style of coding unless some default value is to be provided.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya *Defining* a variable outside the scope of any method will not produce the error you've quoted. *Initializing* the variable to something that's not constant (like a new instance) is the issue.

Comment: @JesseRusak: I read and used that part from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. The first is the location of your `Pet *selectedPet;` line of code. If you just place it in your .m file outside of a method like that, it will be a global variable; this is probably not what you want. You probably want to make it an instance variable. Something like, at the top of your .m file:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    Pet *selectedPet;
}
```

The second problem is that the default value of `selectedPet` is `nil`; that is, it's empty. You need to initialize it first. I would suggest something like this, which creates a fresh pet object and then sets the name and breed:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedPet = [[Pet alloc] init];
    selectedPet.petName = cell.textLabel.text;
    selectedPet.petBreed = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@ Name1: %@",selectedPet.petName,currentPetTemp);

    return indexPath;
}
```

(This assumes you're using ARC; otherwise, you need to do some memory management.)