# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant - Referring a const block from a const struct

Tags: objective-c, xcode, struct, constants, clang

**Environment**

XCode 4.6.2
OSX 10.7.5

**NMFoo.h**

```c
typedef void(^NMFooBlock)();

struct NMFooStruct {
    __unsafe_unretained NMFooBlock fooBlock;
};
typedef struct NMFooStruct NMFooStruct;

@interface NMFoo : NSObject

@end
```

**NMFoo.m**

```c
#import "NMFoo.h"

NMFooBlock const NMFooBlockConst = ^{};

NMFooStruct const NMFooStructConst = { .fooBlock = NMFooBlockConst };

@implementation NMFoo

@end
```

yields a

> error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant NMFooStruct
>   const NMFooStructConst = { .fooBlock = NMFooBlockConst };

Is that the expected behaviour even though NMFooBlockConst is defined as const?

Comment: It's surely 1. not a "contact" but a constant, 2. this has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer came from mikeash.](https://twitter.com/mikeash/status/324625278435459073)

> 'NMFooBlockConst' isn't a compile-time constant expression, so it's not allowed.

Even though the expression ^{} is a compile-time constant, 'NMFooBlockConst' is not according to the language definition.

> Variables aren't compile-time constant expressions, by definition. ^{} is.

The keyword const is unrelated.

> The const keyword has nothing to do with whether something is a compile-time constant expression.

Appreciated Mike.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies here, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143271/73479

However, this will work:

```
NMFooStruct const NMFooStructConst = { .fooBlock = ^{} };
```