# How to use Macro defined value in struct of Object-C?

Tags: objective-c, macros, struct

defined in pch file:

```
#define VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?240:284)
```

then i'll use it in .m file:

```
struct CGRect gPlayerBox[] =
{
    //  x,  y         width,      height
    {   40, 40,         320-80,     VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF - 40-32 }, // player 1 box
    {   40, VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF+33, 320-80,    VIEW_HEIGHT_HALF - 40-32 }  // player 2 box
};
```

but it throw the error:
*Initializer element is not a compile-time constant*

Just wo know know how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The error says it all, `(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?240:284)` is not a compile-time constant; its value has to be determined at runtime but your compiler is initializing gPlayerBox at compile-time.

Comment: Are you using some other macros ?

Comment: When you define a variable outside the scope of a function, that variable's value is actually written into your executable file. This means you can only use a constant value. Since you don't know everything about the runtime environment at compile time (which classes are available, what is their structure, etc.), you cannot create objective c objects until runtime, with the exception of constant strings, which are given a specific structure and guaranteed to stay that way.
  
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6143271/944634

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Mitchell and Bafna.
Finally i defined two different structs using different parameters.
And tried to use them determined by the macro flag "IS_IPHONE5".