# Creating NSObject with NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsobject

I'm trying to create a NSObject class which contains an array which contains the alphabet. When I try to implement the array, I get a warning stating that "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" I've researched it and it has something to do with the program not knowing which value will be used at compile time I don't know how to rectify this with the code I've got. I have the interface and implementation code here:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Alphabet : NSObject {
    NSArray *alphabet;
}
@end

#import "Alphabet.h"

@implementation Alphabet

NSArray *alphabet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z", nil];


@end
```

Comment: You can use properties and lazy-instantiation to achieve this if you are looking for an alternative

Comment: initialise  alphabet array in - (id)init. Have a look at [“Initializer element is not a compile-time constant” why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the objects inside a method like `-(id)init`. You can declare the objects under `@implementation` like:

```
@implementation Alphabet
{
    NSArray *alphabet;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init");
        NSArray *alphabet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

If you initialize an object outside of a method, that object's value needs to be written into the executable file. So you can only use a constant value in that case. You can't create any Objective-C objects except constants until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the array a property and initialize it "lazily":

```
@interface Alphabet : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) alphabet;
@end



#import "Alphabet.h"


@implementation Alphabet {
    NSArray* _alphabet;
}

@synthesize alphabet = _alphabet;


// getter
- (NSArray*) alphabet {
    if (_alphabet == nil) {
        _alphabet = @[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z"];
    }
    return _alphabet;
}


@end
```

**Note:**

The statement

```
_alphabet = @[@"a",@"b",@"c", ..., @"z"];
```

is a short hand for

```
_alphabet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", ..., @"z", nil];
```