# globally usable values ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables, extern

I would like to access few values globally in my iOS App. Apart from using the NSUserDefaults, or initialising in a Class and then creating object wherever I want it, is there another simpler way.

I tried using extern keyword, but arm64 do not support it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what's not simple about `NSUserDefaults`?  And why you really need whatever this is to be global?

Comment: Hi nhgrif, thanks for the comment. I am already using NSUserDefaults extensively, and afraid I will be storing too much, so wanted to know if there is a simpler way. As of now, I am using NSUserDefaults, but would like to shift if there is a better way in terms of device memory usage and app performance.

Comment: There's not really a better way.  Don't worry about performance unless performance is an issue.  And if performance is an issue, start optimizing at the bottlenecks.  NSUserDefaults is unlikely to be a bottleneck.  You won't squeeze much out of performance by finding a different solution to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Thanks a lot nhgrif. That resolves my question. I will add this comment and close this question. Thanks again.

Comment: NSUserDefaults should not be used to substitute for variables storage.  Check for answers posted by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use singleton, but if it is not suitable for you you can use `extern`. It is supported and should be used following way:

Default.h

```
extern NSString *const DGDidLogInNotification;
extern NSArray *array;
```

Default.m

```
#import "Default.h"
NSString *const DGDidLogInNotification = @"DGDidLogInNotification";
NSArray *array;
```

So if you need your variable somewhere - just paste `#import "Default.h"`

Comment: Thanks Avt for this.... yes it works, I was not using *const and that was the issue and my question is wrong that arm64 dont support it.. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Avt, I am able handle NSString in this way, but not NSArray. Can you please give me an example with NSArray used with extern keyword. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: @ashNair I do not think `const` is a problem. Please try updated sample.

Comment: thanks for the sample, do you mind adding the initialising (and adding values) statement as well please. I am getting errors like 'Intializer element is not compile-time constant' and 'Redefinistion of <variablename> with a different type: "int" vs "NSArray * __strong" etc....

Comment: You can declare pointer to NSArray but you can not initialize it in global scope (like NSString). Please read about 'Intializer element is not compile-time constant' error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant

Answer (score 2):

If you have severeal ViewController and you want to access some globale variables I would recommend a Singleton Data-Class like this:

```
/**
 * GlobalData.h
 */ 

@interface GlobalData : NSObject {    

  NSString *foobar;     

}    

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *foobar;    

+(GlobalData*)getInstance;    

@end  


/**
 * GlobalData.m    
 */

@implementation GlobalData
@synthesize foobar;

static GlobalData *instance = nil;    

+(GlobalData *)getInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {    
        if( instance == nil ) {    
            instance = [GlobalData new];    
        }    
    }    
    return instance;    
}
```

You can now access the same variables from everywhere like this:

```
#import GlobalData.h

GlobalData *globalData = [GlobalData getInstance];  
globalData.foobar = @"foobar";
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I'd recommend creating properties in your AppDelegate's header file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL someGlobalVariable;

@end
```

Then, to access (in this case assign) the variable in your view controller,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).someGlobalVariable = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a file named {project_name}-Prefix.pch in your project. You can declare any object or variable in this file and it will be accessible in any other place of the project. For example:

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif


#ifdef __OBJC__
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif


NSInteger someVariable = 10;
```

Now you can access to someVariable anywhere. Also you can import to Prefix.pch any file where you have variable declared and all public variables and objects will be accessible in all other files.

Comment: Igor, thats very helpful. Any recommendation how this should be used, i.e are there any good practices associated...eg. can I stores hundreds of values in a array here... etc?