# Initializer element is not a compile time constant

Tags: objective-c

Using objective-c to write a program. I'm getting an error (initializer element is not a compile-time constant) and am not sure I follow why it's occurring. I'm just trying to initialize an array. I'm also using xcode6. My questions are: how can I rewrite this correctly in Objective-c and what would it look like in the new Swift? Also why is there an error - I don't follow how to implement some of the other threads on this question?

Name.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Name : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;

@end
```

Name.m

```
#import "Name.h"

@implementation Name

NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //error shows up here - initializer element is not a compile-time constant

[myArray addObject:@"Object 1"];

[myArray addObject:@"Object 2"];

[myArray addObject:@"Object 3"];

@end
```

Comment: One question a the time, please. Also, if you want to translate this to swift, go ahead and try yourself. If you have problems, come here with a specific question.

Comment: This is in response to your comment on your deleted question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24252665/365496. Yes, `uniform_real_distribution` combined with the `mt19937` engine should be quite uniform. Also note that when using the `<random>` library you do not need to seed using `srand()`. Initializing the engine (`mt19937`) is sufficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should init the variable only inside a method

try override

```
 -(id) init
 {
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
  {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
 }
```

Comment: Where do I put the addObject methods?

Comment: NSMutableArray *myArray = @[@"Object 1",@"Object 2",@"Object 3"];

Comment: Does this go after the init method?

Comment: Sorry, The last comment wasn't correct as it return an NSArray and not NSMutableArray - so you won't be able to add more objects afterwards if that's your intention.
You should call 
    [myArray addObject:@"Object 1"];
    [myArray addObject:@"Object 2"];
    [myArray addObject:@"Object 3"];
right after the initialisation call.
i.e at the init method

Comment: I get an error saying "Expected identifier" at the alloc init line. -(id) init { self = [super init]; if(self) { NSMutableArray *myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [myArray addObject:@"Object 1"]; [myArray addObject:@"Object 2"]; [myArray addObject:@"Object 3"]; } return self;

Comment: try copying it now. 
I had [[[ instead [[

Comment: That worked. Was it related to this comment "Because you are asking the compiler to initialize a static variable with code that is inherently dynamic."?

 Do I need to be aware of any new issues when using this property in the rest of the class?

Answer (score 3):

**Error**

As the error say, you can only initialize compile time constant in the implementation of your class

This will work:

```
NSString* abcd = @"test";
```

Because `@"test"` is a constant and will never change after the compilation of your code.

`[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` is not a constant and this is why you got an error. You will have to implement an `init` method to initialize your array.

**Swift**

For the swift part of your question:

You can still use NSArray in swift or use the swift Array type. 
You can check out the [Working with Cocoa Data Types Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) or the [Apple collections types Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html).

If you still want to use NSArray in swift :

```
var array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
array.addObject("test1")
array.addObject("test2")
// or
array:NSMutableArray = ["test1", "test2"]
```

Or if you want to use the swift array :

```
var array:String[] = ["test1", "test2"]
// or
var array:String[] = String[]()
array.append("test1")
array.append("test2")
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful...how does it know the array is not a constant and will change after compile time? In the initial code I am just using strings?

Comment: alloc and init are methods of the NSMutableArray class. The compiler cannot know what those methods will return before calling them during the execution of your code. It's not possible for the compiler to know what the methods return at compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try to edit you "Building Settings"->"Compile Sources As" to "Objective-C++", maybe can solve your problem.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks