# How do I use an NSDecimalNumber as a const?

Tags: objective-c, constants, nsdecimalnumber

I have a list of `const static double`s. I want to convert them to `const static NSDecimalNumber*`s. **Is this possible? If not, what's a good alternative?**

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: See (probably a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant

Comment: @JoshCaswell https://i.imgur.com/fvasgdT.png

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other Objective-C numbers (e.g. NSInteger), `NSDecimalNumber` is a runtime-evaluated object, and thus cannot be evaluated at compile time. Due to this, you must treat it as the object it is.

So, replace your:

```
const static double YourNumber = 123.456;

@implementation YourClass
// ...
@end
```

with:

```
NSDecimalNumber *YourNumber;

@implementation YourClass
+(void) initialize
{
    YourNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"123.456"];
}

// ...
@end
```