# extern const compiler error: Initialiser element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: objective-c, c, clang

I have a custom struct defined in the following way

```
typedef struct {
    CGFloat value;
    CGAffineTransform transform;
} MyStruct;
```

My intent is to define a constant representing the default content of this struct.

I've tried doing this with `extern const`:

*.h file

```
extern MyStruct const MyStructDefault;
```

*m file

```
MyStruct const MyStructDefault = { 0., CGAffineTransformIdentity };
```

But Xcode points an error next to the `CGAffineTransformIdentity`

> Initialiser element is not a compile-time constant

I know I can use `#define` in the header file or make the `MyStructDefault()` a function, but I'm curious why the original approach doesn't work, since `CGAffineTransformIdentity` is also defined as extern const thereafter must be a compile-time constant.

**Update**

This question is not really a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant), the fact that `extern const` is not really a compile-time resolved constant is not obvious.

Comment: extern is not resolved at compile-time, but at linking-time

Comment: @trojanfoe: Different question, and different answer than the proposed duplicate.

Comment: If objective-C is anything like C, then `const` is not a constant, but read-only variable, and thus cannot be used in constant expressions like in initializer.