# Error: "initializer element is not a compiled-time constant" When i write this code

Tags: objective-c, sinch

i am instantiating a sinch client object and it gives the error "initializer element is not a compiled-time constant"

```
id <SINClient> sinchClient = [sinch clientWithApplicationKey:@"<application Key>"

applicationSecret: @"<application secret>"

environmentHost: @"sandbox.sinch.com"

userId: @"<user id>"];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)

Comment: posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant