# Fix error "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"

Tags: theos, tweak

I'm trying to create a tweak for iOS, but when I'm going to compile the tweak, I get this error:
"initializer element is not a compile-time constant".

```
//Sound path
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Library/Application Support/joselito/"] pathForResource:@"joselito" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundPath];
```

Comment: One simple google search would have helped! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant)