# '" error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int number_scores = get_int("How many scores do you need: ");
float average(int array[]);
int main(void)
{
    int number_scores = get_int("How many scores do you need: ");
    int scores[N];
    for(int i = 0; number_scores < 3; i++)
    {
        scores[i]= get_int("Scores: ");
    }
    printf("Average: %f\n", average(scores));
}
float average(int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_scores;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i]
    }
    return sum / (float)number_scores;
}
```

This is my code I am trying to print of the average between the number of test scores the user is giving us which is int number_scores. But when I try to "make"the program in C i get this error"scores.c:3:21: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant".

I have looked in the [Compiler error: "initializer element is not a compile-time constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143107/compiler-error-initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant) but I didn't get anything out of that from my program as my program i have already made number_scores a int variable and said get_int for the input for the user. If anybody wants the docs for get_int. Here it is https://manual.cs50.io/ the official documentation for get_int. Thanks in advance if anybody could help me solve this problem.

Comment: `number_scores` is a local variable in `main()`, you can't use it in `average()`. You need to pass it as an additional argument.

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: Barmar scores.c:3:21 is getting the error

Comment: I wanted number_scores to be used for the entire program so I thought I had to put it before main?

Comment: When I wrote that first comment I didn't notice that it was both global and also local.

Answer (score 2):

Take the initialization out of the global variable declaration. Inside `main()` you should assign the variable.

You never declared the variable `N` used in the array declaration. That should be `number_scores`.

The condition `number_scores < 3` doens't change in your loop, so you have an infinite loop. It should be `i < number_scores`.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int number_scores;
float average(int array[]);
int main(void)
{
    number_scores = get_int("How many scores do you need: ");
    int scores[number_scores];
    for(int i = 0; i < number_scores; i++)
    {
        scores[i]= get_int("Scores: ");
    }
    printf("Average: %f\n", average(scores));
}
float average(int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number_scores;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i]
    }
    return sum / (float)number_scores;
}
```

Even better would be to not use a global variable at all, and make this a parameter of the `average` function.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float average(int array[], int num_scores);

int main(void)
{
    int number_scores = get_int("How many scores do you need: ");
    int scores[number_scores];
    for(int i = 0; i < number_scores; i++)
    {
        scores[i]= get_int("Scores: ");
    }
    printf("Average: %f\n", average(scores), number_scores);
}
float average(int array[], num_scores)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_scores;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i]
    }
    return sum / (float)num_scores;
}
```